# How the function works !(n & 1) , why ! before (), and why n & 1 , what does it mean?

Tags: c, boolean

How does `!(n & 1)` work, why `!` before `()`, and why `n & 1` ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int even(int n)
{
    return !(n & 1);
}

int main()
{
    int pom, count=0,n;
    while(scanf("%d", &n))
    {
        if(even(n))

        {
            count++;
        }

    }
    printf("%d", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The expression `n & 1` is `1` if `n` is odd and `0` if n is even. The `!` operator treats the expression as boolean (where `1` becomes `true` and `0` `false`) and inverts the boolean value. The return statement implicitly converts the value back to `int` giving `1` if `n` is even and `0` if `n` was odd.

Comment: yes but is it a recursive or a regular function ?

Comment: @TommyD This function is not calling itself, so it is not recursive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function uses the bitwise `&` operator to check if something is even. The number `1` is represented as `0001` in  binary. If there is an even number such as `14` which is `1110` in 32-bit binary then `114 & 1` will be `0`. This is because there are no common bits between the two numbers

```
1 1 1 0 - 14
0 0 0 1 - 1
0 0 0 0 - 0 (No common bit)
```

Putting the `!` inverts the result so it takes the fasly `0` and turns it into a truthy integer. However, if the number is odd, like `15` which is `1111` in binary there is a common digit and `1111 & 1 = 1`. Shown here

```
1 1 1 1 - 15
0 0 0 1 - 1
0 0 0 1 - 1
```

and `!1` turns the truthy `1` into the falsy `0`. The rule is that all even number `& 1` will be `0` as there are never common bits but all odd number `& 1` will be `1` as there is always a common bit. When the `!` inverts the result of the bitwise operator, you can figure out if a number is even or odd.

**Edit**: I realized that the term invert could be ambiguous. What I mean by invert is that it does this. `!n` is `0` if `n != 0` and is not `0` if `n == 0`.

Answer (score 3):

- `!` is a logical NOT operator. When you pass it a value that is zero, you get back one; if you pass a non-zero, you get back zero.
- `n & 1` masks the `int` with `1`, which has a binary representation `0000000000001`, i.e. only the last bit is set
- Even numbers have zero in their last bit; odd numbers have one in their last bit

Now you can see how the formula `!(n & 1)` lets you distinguish even numbers from odd numbers.

Another common way to tell if a number is even is to check divisibility by 2:

```
return n % 2 == 0;
```

Comment: The latter way is much better, as it clarifies the intent. Decent compiler will translate it into `and` instruction anyway.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski Yes, you're right. G++, without -O3 or -O2, detected this. `bool is_even(int n) { return n % 2 == 0; }` compiles to ```movl %edi, -4(%rbp)
 movl -4(%rbp), %eax
 andl $1, %eax
 testl %eax, %eax
 sete %al```

wherein you can clearly see the and, as well as the negation (test and sete)